# What does the phrase "He got nothing on me" mean?

Tags: american-english

I was listening a song by Charlie Puth and he says:

> Superman got nothing on me

What does it mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Charlie's saying that he's equivalent to Superman. "Got nothing on me" is a common phrase for saying that something has no advantages over or is in no way superior to another thing (or person in this case).

Comment: Yeah, he means nothing in comparison to you; does not compare to you.

Comment: It  does NOT mean equivalent. It means inferior. @retron's answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This phrase was addressed [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/102686/what-does-have-nothing-on-someone-mean-here). It means Superman is inferior to Charlie and can't compete with him. The expression may be related to idioms like "having someone's number" or "having dirt on someone", i.e. having some advantage over a rival.